# Record Header as part of Handshake messages on TCP/IP stack

Tags: tls, openssl

I knew that the format of the TLS handshake message is as below.

"Record header+Handshake layer header+ Handshake message"

Now i have confusion while analyzing the TLS handshake messages on TCP.
How the structure would look like from server in response to client hello.

Note:- Since TCP can handle segmentation i believe server hello,server crt ,server key exchange,server hello done can be handled can be received in segments and provide to tls.

There fore how does the raw date look like at the end of the all frames received till TCP ?

will be it be as below ?

Record header+Handshake layer header+**Server hello** +Record header+Handshake layer header+**Server crt**+Record header+Handshake layer header+server key exchange+Record header+Handshake layer header+server hello done

```
  or will it be omitting the record header ??
```

Record header+Handshake layer header+**Server hello** +Handshake layer header+**Server crt**+Handshake layer header+server key exchange+Handshake layer header+server hello done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is implementation-dependent. The RFC says clearly that messages with the same content type **MAY** be put together into the same record but also that a single message might spread over multiple records. From [RFC 5246 (TLS 1.2) section 6.2.1 Fragmentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2.1):

> Client
> message boundaries are not preserved in the record layer (i.e.,
> multiple client messages of the same ContentType MAY be coalesced
> into a single TLSPlaintext record, or a single message MAY be
> fragmented across several records).

Comment: @ steffenUllrich thanks for the information!!. I am trying to analyze the TLS handshake traffic.Below is the question based on the above clarification:- 1) The above statement holds good for Handshake messages as well ? 2) if the single hand shake message is spread along multiple messages ,How does the Client side implementation  know that the new message is continuation of the last message?

Comment: @kumars: a) Since Handshake is a single content type this is also true for Handshake messages. b)  The messages (like Handshake) have their own length information and thus it is clear if the message is complete or not. If not complete it will be continued in the next record. For example in RFC 5246 section 7.4 you will find the struct Handshake with the field `length`.

Comment: Remember Change Cipher Spec, although used only in handshake, is a different record type thus 'unmixy'.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Thanks for pointing out that there is a difference between "Handshake" as a specific content type and "Handshake" as the process which includes messages with different content types, including but not only the "Handshake" content type. Mixing of messages within the same record cares about the content type, not about the process.

Comment: thanks @steffenUllrich,@dave_thompson_085..Its clear right now.

Comment: I've a question concerning the word "client" in 6.2.1 of RFC5246, you are citing above: is this word related to the client in the communication relationship between TLS server and TLS client or is it related to the client of the TLS record layer in the layer stack of the implementation, which are, according to 6.2 of RFC5246, the "higher layers"?

Comment: @wollud1969: *" the client of the TLS record layer "* - this is it. There is no difference how TLS records are handled in TLS client and TLS server.

Answer (score 0):

All the PDUs of TLS (client hello, cert, server hello and so on) can be segmented by TCP with no problem, in general is responsibility of the operating system take all the parts and once all the data is ready at Layer7 (Application) then pass to the application (the program). If you want to think in sockets for example, you can think on a write operation of 5000 bytes that TCP will split on different packets, but there is no IP fragmentation here, is the TCP layer that splits the 5000 bytes. On the other hand, the receiver will wait on a receive system call (recv, read, or whatever) until all the 5000 bytes are received on the TCP stack and then unblock the syscall and pass the control to the application.